# Sizeof(char)

Tags: char, c++

Читаю сейчас на хабре [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/251091/). Там говорится следующее:

> char — это всегда ровно один байт и во всех стандартах C и C++ sizeof (char) == 1 (но при этом стандарты не гарантируют, что в байте содержится именно 8 бит :))

Я слышал об этом и раньше, но всегда не мог понять, в чем смысл того, что в байте может быть не 8 бит? Наверное, это где-то действительно есть, но зачем это нужно? В чем необходимость, что в байте может быть 7 или 9 (или сколько там еще) бит, и не создает ли это больше проблем, чем пользы?

Comment: [Было тут уже](http://hashcode.ru/questions/118221) хорошее обсуждение подобного вопроса  
(и ссылки архитектуры с байтом не из 8 бит там есть).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приведённая цитата - скорее, историческая ремарка, чем реальное предупреждение. В старых (*очень* старых) архитектурах процессоров использовались и 7-битные, и 6-битные, и даже 32-битные байты. Ранняя версия [ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) была семибитной, также существовала [семибитная версия КОИ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%98-7). Но со временем стандартом де-факто стал восьмибитный байт, так как процессорам было проще оперировать величинами, чей размер выражался степенью двойки (8 = 2^3). Позже размер байта в 8 бит был закреплён стандартом [IEC 80000-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_80000-13).

Comment: Нет, это как раз понятно, что раньше были такие архитектуры. Но вопрос в том, в чем был смысл такого? Для чего то же это делали.

Comment: ответ прост. Так было удобно. Просто победил 8битный байт. Он ничем не лучше и не хуже 16 битного байта или 36 битного (и такой был).

Сейчас, когда практически у каждого есть компьютер и не один, сложно поверить, что ещё лет 50-60 назад компьютеры были "штучные", под заказ. Захотел заказчик 155 бит в байте - сделают.

Comment: Ну и по поводу семи- и шестибитных байтов: когда у вас блок памяти объёмом в килобайт представляет собой тяжеленный ящик, набитый ферритами, вы будете сознательно экономить каждый бит, игнорируя удобство.

Comment: @fori1ton @KoVadim спасибо!

Comment: Чет ностальжи нахлынуло: вспомнил времена, когда 8 кб оперативки были верхом совершенства, а у меня был личный винчестер аж на 2.5 мегабайта размером с приличный портфель и я таскал его домой, чтобы никакая сука не могла его стырить. Приезжал на работу ставил его в накопитель, включал, расскручивал выкуривал сигарету и только потом монтировал (иначе `mount` проваливался, поскольку винт не успевал раскрутиться)

Comment: Ага, это 23-тье приближается.